# drag and drop a node into another node

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to learn JavaFX by implementing a chess game.
My problem is I have no idea how to move a piece by dragging and dropping .
In my code I have a 2D array of label in which label contains an ImageView.
I want to know how to determine another piece (node) under the dragged piece.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to use `setOnDragDetected()` method for the item you want to drag,then use the `setOnDragOver()` on the target item to determine which [TransferMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/TransferMode.html) is accepting and `setOnDragDropped()` on target method when the drop is done.Finally `setOnDragComplete()` on the original item to determine that the drag was successful.

1)Link for more info from oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm)

2)A nice example [here](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/05/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-function-in-a-javafx-application/)

3)A second example which is easy to understand:

```
    /**
 * Demonstrates a drag-and-drop feature.
 */
public class HelloDragAndDrop extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Hello Drag And Drop");

        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 200);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGREEN);

        final Text source = new Text(50, 100, "DRAG ME");
        source.setScaleX(2.0);
        source.setScaleY(2.0);

        final Text target = new Text(250, 100, "DROP HERE");
        target.setScaleX(2.0);
        target.setScaleY(2.0);

        source.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
            /* drag was detected, start drag-and-drop gesture */
            System.out.println("onDragDetected");

            /* allow any transfer mode */
            Dragboard db = source.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

            /* put a string on dragboard */
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(source.getText());
            db.setContent(content);

            event.consume();
        });

        target.setOnDragOver(event -> {
            /* data is dragged over the target */
            System.out.println("onDragOver");

            /*
             * accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node and if it
             * has a string data
             */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                /* allow for both copying and moving, whatever user chooses */
                event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        target.setOnDragEntered(event -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
            System.out.println("onDragEntered");
            /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
            if (event.getGestureSource() != target && event.getDragboard().hasString()) {
                target.setFill(Color.GREEN);
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        target.setOnDragExited(event -> {
            /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
            target.setFill(Color.BLACK);

            event.consume();
        });

        target.setOnDragDropped(event -> {
            /* data dropped */
            System.out.println("onDragDropped");
            /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
            Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
            boolean success = false;
            if (db.hasString()) {
                target.setText(db.getString());
                success = true;
            }
            /*
             * let the source know whether the string was successfully
             * transferred and used
             */
            event.setDropCompleted(success);

            event.consume();
        });

        source.setOnDragDone(event -> {
            /* the drag-and-drop gesture ended */
            System.out.println("onDragDone");
            /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
            if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                source.setText("");
            }

            event.consume();
        });

        root.getChildren().add(source);
        root.getChildren().add(target);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: @M.Sianaki when an answer works for you mark it as solution.:)